# access a project link on ubuntu machine without port number

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have a project running on ubuntu (installed on vm machine(ipaddress-172.22.240.54) on server ), jboss server port 8180

I need to access that link via  `http://172.22.240.54/employeeConnect/rest`(without mentioning port number)

What changes are required in httpd file and server.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the following to your httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass /employeeConnect/rest http://localhost:8180/employeeConnect/rest
ProxyPassReverse /employeeConnect/rest http://localhost:8180/employeeConnect/rest
```